# How to set column to be linked in an imported data list in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint-2010

I have an Access database with 1800 records, when moved to Sharepoint list, it randomly sets the linked column,
For example: I have the following columns:
"Badge No.", "Name" and "File status".

Every time when move it (import) to Sharepoint list, it sets "File status" to be linked to the item.
How to set the column "Name" to be linked to the item ?

Answer (score 0):

It not quite clear here, but you do seem to be suggesting that you have more than one table involved here. If you going to send tables up to SharePoint and use the new relational features of SharePoint, then you need to setup the relationships in those Access tables BEFORE you send them up to SharePoint.

> Every time when moved to Sharepoint list, it sets "File status" to be linked to the item.

Hum, it not clear what you mean by "item" here? Are you talking about more than one table and their PK (primary key values) and a FK (foreign key) value used to relate these two tables (or is there even more than one table involved here – I cannot tell from your description?

So sending a table up to SharePoint is in general neither an issue nor problem. Sending up tables with related data – well that is a major difference of an issue here.

As such when moving up related tables of data, this can be a challenge with SQL server or any system since often the PK auto number values will be changed on the target system during an up-load. And such a setup thus often suggests that you need a cascade update of child tables to keep the related data intact during an upload.

However, do keep in mind Access CAN upload data to SharePoint, and SharePoint WILL + CAN respect the related tables, but it will also change the PK values during an up-load. This means it is VERY VERY important to setup relationships in tables that conform to SharePoint, else you lose the logical relationship you have between tables due to auto number be re-numbered (changed) during  a upload.

However, I do explain in the following video how to up-size related data from Access, and the built in tools WILL allow this type of up-sizing of data and child tables and their FK values will be automatic changed for you.

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL27E956A1537FE1C5&feature=plcp

Comment: Its only one table with 1800 records in Microsoft access.. and I import it to sharepoint 2010 .... and what I mean by "linked to the item" is I want "Name" to be clickable when click it, it takes to view item details